# force php strtotime to use UTC

Tags: php, timestamp, strtotime

I've seen a few questions about this but not a clear answer... strtotime() will use the default timezone set for PHP when converting the string to a unix timestamp.

However, I want to convert a string to unix timestamp in UTC. Since there is no parameter for doing so, how can this be done?

The string I'm trying to convert is: 2011-10-27T20:23:39, which is already in UTC. I want to represent that as a unix timestamp also in UTC.

Thank you

Comment: Also consider using `new DateTimeZone('UTC');`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34651091/1066234

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the system default timezone before making the `strtotime` call:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo strtotime('2011-10-27T20:23:39')."\n";

// Proof:
print_r(getdate(strtotime('2011-10-27T20:23:39')));

// IMPORTANT: It's possible that you will want to
// restore the previous system timezone value here.
// It would need to have been saved with
// date_default_timezone_get().
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/apMQ2)**.

Comment: Would that cause issues with the rest of the script though? I guess I could set it back afterwards?

Comment: @Brian: It could cause issues, yes. But as long as you set it back there will be no problem.

Answer (score 23):

I realize this question is very old, but I found another option that can be helpful.
Instead of setting and then reverting php's time zone, you can specify the timezone as a part of the string you pass to strtotime like so:

```
echo date_default_timezone_get();
output: America/Chicago

echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2011-10-27T20:23:39'));
output: 2011-10-28 01:23:39

echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2011-10-27T20:23:39 America/Chicago'));
output: 2011-10-28 01:23:39

echo gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2011-10-27T20:23:39 UTC'));
output 2011-10-27 20:23:39
```

Note: I am on PHP 5.5.9, but this should work in any php version.

Comment: This is easier but you have to watch out for user input.  If you just sending in what a user has typed you never know if they are going to include the timezone or something that will mess the string up.

Answer (score 4):

Both other answers are really fine. As I have the same issue, I want to offer a third option.

```
$utc = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$dt = new DateTime('2011-10-27T20:23:39', $utc);
var_dump($dt->format('U'));
```

gives `string(10) "1319747019"`

Comment: This does not work if there is a timezone present in the datetime string.

Comment: Maybe, but this is a solution for the question. Additionally, what's different from the other solutions!? In all other cases, a present timezone can lead to unwanted result.

Comment: Using DateTimeZone as Parameter suggests that it would always use this timezone.